# Can Android NFC Peer2Peer communicate with a non-Android NFC Device (NOT Tag)?

Tags: android, nfc, android-beam

I know Android NFC device can use Android Beam to share small size information like URL.
And, I know the Android NFC can't pretend be a tag.

In my potential Access Control project, we want to use similar tech to share 32 bytes Digital Key and Authentication ID (8 bytes) with a NFC PCB module.

**Is it possible?**

If it is, is there any framework or lib to provide high level API?
Do we need use low layer api to rebuild something like Android Beam?

Comment: Do You need smth like discussed here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/hoFX1AcsmvM (it has some useful links to API which operates open communication protocols)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes,It's possible.I developed one project like that before.

In non-android device, you should implement LLCP and SNEP(or NPP) protocol. And for the phone, you should develop your own application to provide the message.

In last project, we use [libnfc](https://code.google.com/p/libnfc/) to drive the PN532 chip on PC, then use [libllcp](https://code.google.com/p/libllcp/) for the LLCP layer, and implemented SNEP stack. At last develop our own service and application.

Maybe you can have a try like this way, or implement the protocols I mentioned above.